# Using UIView (AwesomeMenu) -> view doesn't appear

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I tried using AwesomeMenu in my code, the one which is here:
https://github.com/levey/AwesomeMenu

It's usage is very simple, as listed in the github page. I followed it as-is. But the menu is not appearing in the UI. Am using iOS 5.0 and Xcode 4.2, with iOS Simulator for testing.

This is what I did:

**in my ViewController.h**

```
...
#import "AwesomeMenu.h"
#import "AwesomeMenuItem.h"
...
// I included the AwesomeMenuDelegate here 
@interface com_FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,      UITableViewDataSource,AwesomeMenuDelegate> {
...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AwesomeMenu *awesomeMenu;
...
```

**In the Storyboard**
I have created a UIView instance, positioned & resized it where I want it to, changed its class to type 'AwesomeMenu', and linked its 'Referencing Outlet' to the IBOutlet property 'awesomeMenu'.

**In ViewController.m**

```
...
@synthesize awesomeMenu;
...
AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem1;
AwesomeMenuItem *starMenuItem2;
...
...

// This method seems to be getting called, as I see the log messages
-(void) initializeSpringMenu {
    NSLog(@"InitializeSpringMenu: entered");
    UIImage *storyMenuItemImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GooglePlus.png"];
    UIImage *storyMenuItemImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GooglePlus.png"];
    UIImage *starImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mail-icon.png"];

    starMenuItem1 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] 
                                    initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                    highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed 
                                    ContentImage:starImage 
                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];
    starMenuItem2 = [[AwesomeMenuItem alloc] 
                                    initWithImage:storyMenuItemImage
                                    highlightedImage:storyMenuItemImagePressed 
                                    ContentImage:starImage 
                                    highlightedContentImage:nil];

    // Now, setup the menu and the options
    awesomeMenu = [[AwesomeMenu alloc] 
                initWithFrame:self.view.bounds 
                menus:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:starMenuItem1, starMenuItem2, nil]];
    awesomeMenu.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"initializeSpringMenu: Done initializing it");
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [self initializeSpringMenu];
    ...
}
```

I think it's pretty straightforward & I don't see what am missing here. Is it the bounds when doing an 'init' of AwesomeMenu? Can someone please help? The view appears blank in the UI when I run the App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jean,

you need to add `AwesomeMenu` to your ViewController's view. Modify the end of `initializeSpringMenu` as follows:

```
    .......

    // Now, setup the menu and the options
    awesomeMenu = [[AwesomeMenu alloc] 
                  initWithFrame:self.view.bounds 
                  menus:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:starMenuItem1, starMenuItem2, nil]];
    awesomeMenu.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubView:awesomeMenu] // <-- THIS ADDS THE AWESOME VIEW TO YOUR VIEWCONTROLLERS VIEW
    NSLog(@"initializeSpringMenu: Done initializing it");
}
```

That should be all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that as the first thing, in vain. It simply gives the same result whether or not that line ('addSubview') is present. Anyways, I have linked the 'awesomeMenu' property IBOutlet in Interface Builder; so, IMO, it really should not matter whether I add 'addSubview' in the code or not, right?

Comment: I think I did a subtle (or big!?!) mistake. I tried this earlier
    "[self.view.window addSubview:awesomeMenu];"
in vain. Now, after seeing your reply, I removed all the code, slowly added them one-by-one, and tried adding:
    "[self.view addSubview:awesomeMenu];"
it works partially (though some trivial issues seem to be there)...atleast am seeing the menu in the UI when I run the App! Hey, thank you so much!